# Security Roles required for Web Forms For Marketers email save action

Tags: wffm, security, role-management, editor-user-permissions, webforms

I have been trying to tidy up permissions on our Sitecore install. My admin account has every permission haphazardly applied which causes all kinds of issues, but I can create WFFM forms with email save actions fine.

However our new, tidy, basic role (called 'Content Editor') receives a 500 error at the final step. They are able to add an email save action, but when clicking onto that action, they receive a 500 error. Experience tells me this is a missing permissions:

[image: 500 error]

I found [this article](https://doc.sitecore.net/web_forms_for_marketers/web_forms_for_marketers/setting_up_web_forms/installing/the_security_roles_in_the_web_forms_for_marketers_module) in the docs and I have ensured that our Content Editor role has the following permissions:

- Author
- Sitecore Client Securing
- Sitecore  Marketer Form Author
- Sitecore Client Authoring
- Sitecore Client Designing
- Sitecore Client Developing

However, the 500 error still shows. Any ideas on what I could be missing here?

Comment: can you verify log file, to see which error is thrown

Comment: Hi @VladIobagiu I don't have dev access to this site unfortunately. So unless there's a way to see the error log from within the Sitecore CMS itself, probably not easily...

Comment: @Mike To see your logs within Sitecore, please go to Sitecore->Reporting Tools->Log Viewer. We will be waiting for more info so we can help you :D

Comment: @VladIobagiu I opened the log viewer and I can see log files from today. However they are all between 0 and 3 bytes in size, and all the recent ones simply contain the phrase: "This file is empty or cannot be opened for reading.". I tried downloading the file, and it is indeed empty when viewed with a text editor.

Comment: @Mike Are you sure that this "Content Editor" role has also permissions for "/sitecore/System/Modules/Web Forms for Marketers" and its subitems. One thing is to have proper roles and another to have also all needed update/write permissions. Check permissions with Access Viewer and set permissions via Security editor tools. Hopefully this will be your problem ;)

Comment: @PeterProchazka I just added those permissions, and still encounter the same 500 error when trying to edit the email save action unfortunately. Any other ideas?

Comment: Hi @Mike, I took my original example I created for the training that you used to setup the role, and assigned "Sitecore Marketer Form Author" to that role, and that's all that was needed.  I am to create the Send E-mail Message and there are no 500 errors.  We need to find out what the 500 error has in it, because it might be something unrelated to permissions, could be a WFFM error for example.  What version of Sitecore and WFFM are you using?  Are you able to get past the same step with your admin login?

Comment: HI @DylanYoung. Yes, the admin profile is able to create a form and add an email recipient. Sitecore.NET 8.1 (rev. 160519), Web Forms for Marketers 8.1.rev. 160523

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who finds this in future: My problem was the 'Author' role being applied to my user. For whatever reason, this conflicts with WFFM. Removing the role has no noticeable effects on my users and seems to have resolved the issue.